# Retrofit 2 cannot get response

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, connection-pool

I have an android app that home screen make few requests to server(5-10 requests by enqueue() depend on app logic) but when i come with adding one more request, i cannot get response from log.
I config retrofit following code:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
        @Override
        public void log(String message) {
            Log.d(TAG, message);
        }
    });
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    httpBuilder.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
    ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
            .cipherSuites(
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
            .build();
    httpBuilder
            .readTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpBuilder.connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));
```

and i call request by:

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = getCallRequest();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            // process failure case
        }
    });
```

but HttpLoggingInterceptor do not log response of this request as 
<-- logging....
It's not occur in all requests, sometime ok so i think the reason is connection pool but i try the code by adding the line:

```
httpBuilder.connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(10, 5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
```

but its not effected. Please help me find out the way to resolve this. Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry i cant push full code for come security reasons, if someone cant help me let me know you need what?, Thanks

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: or it is possible for you to test the requests in postman first?

Comment: of course bro, I check log on server and server sent response back but i cant see that on client log

Comment: and postman request is ok

Comment: @NoumanCh i'm not getting any errors, but no response to be return